# Python - gui - tkinter Getting entry values

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I'm making a python tkinter gui which uses walmarts api and lets you search any item based on a id number. What I can't get to work is the submit button, it wont do anything. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


def displayText():

    global queryurl
    global ItemIdEntry
    global GetItemId


    if ItemIdEntry.get().strip() == "":
    tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Item Checker", "Enter an item id number! ")
    else:
        try:
            import urllib.request as urllib2
        except ImportError:
            import urllib2

        import json

        GetItemId = ItemIdEntry.get().strip()



        queryurl = ('http://walmartlabs.api.mashery.com/v1/items/'+GetItemId+'?format=json&apiKey=phutmkv9t262zj7dmbk8hkec')

        f = urllib2.urlopen(queryurl)
        json_string = f.read().decode('utf-8' )
        parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

        itemName = parsed_json['name']
        currentprice = parsed_json['salePrice']
        upc = parsed_json['upc']
        producturl = parsed_json['productUrl']
        description = parsed_json['shortDescription']
        online = parsed_json['availableOnline']
        modelnumber = parsed_json['modelNumber']

        print ('Name:', itemName)
        print ('Current Price:', '$', currentprice)
        print ('Upc Number:', upc)
        print ('Model Number:', modelnumber)
        print ('Purchaseable Online:', online)
        print ('Description:', description)
        print ('Product Url:', producturl)

        f.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (250, 100, 250, 100))
    var = tk.StringVar(root)
    root.title("Item Checker")   

    itemName = Label(root, text="Please enter an id number")
    itemName.pack(side = TOP)

    ItemIdEntry = Entry(root, bd =5)
    ItemIdEntry.pack(side = TOP)

    submitbutton = tkinter.Button(root, text ="Submit", command = displayText)#Submit button
    submitbutton.pack()




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to be more specific.  Is there an error or you don't know how to get it to work as you want.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I just don't quite know how to get it to work.

Comment: "don't quite know how to get it to work." is not actually any question. Please be specific. Which line does not work, any errors? What value of GetItemId should be used for testing? expected outcome?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. What I want is, after entering an entry value and hitting my submit button. I want it to print my json parsing. But nothing is happening. So how do i make my submit button display text after hitting it?

Comment: I tried to help, but I dont know how to replicate this problem, as I dont know what to put into the entry value. When I put 34, for example, I get bunch of erros. So the code in the displayText is being exected, but crashes due to `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`.

Comment: Oh. Try entering "38665241" It's a walmart id number. If you do that you'll see exactly what I'm getting.

Comment: Ok. So it seems to be working for me. Check this [gif](http://i.imgur.com/lsQrhC0.gif) and the code I used is [here](http://pastebin.com/MHwiqjWr). The change I did was indentation problem, but I think its because of copy-paste here.

Comment: Oh, so it was indentation issue after all. Strange that you did not get any errors that indentation is wrong. Oh Well. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it offical. The problem was with indentation. Specifically instead of this:

```
if ItemIdEntry.get().strip() == "":
tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Item Checker", "Enter an item id number! ")
```

there should be:

```
if ItemIdEntry.get().strip() == "":
    tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Item Checker", "Enter an item id number! ")
```

Answer (score 0):

What would you expect? You printing values in that function. You don't evet display them. For example instead of this;

```
print ('Name:', itemName)
```

You should use this;

```
lbl = Label(text="{}".format(itemName), fg="red",font="Times 35 bold")
lbl.pack()
```

So that whenever you click your button, your function will display them.